# how to get a different html for odd/even posts?

Tags: posts, query

```
    query posts
      if posts exist
        then begin the loop
          if post is even: <h1>title</h1><p>content</p>
          if post is odd: <div>its image</div>
```

this is what i'm trying to get, a different output for odd/even posts: for even posts we will show the title and the content while for odd posts we will show its image (the thumbnail, for example).
How to get this result?

I query post in this way

```
query_posts('category_name=category-name');
```

then i don't know how to continue

Comment: Post all of you code please. And don't use `query_posts` at all. This question [has been answered multiple times](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=nth), by the way. Do some research and edit the question with something more specific.

Comment: @s_ha_dum sorry, I don't have code. If I had the code I would not be here.

Comment: Ok. I gave you a place to start. This question has been asked and answered many times in many variations. And second, you have _no_ loop code at all? The question format for the site is "How can I fix this broken code?" not "Can you pretty please write my code for me?"

Answer (score 14):

You don't need a new variable for counting posts, WordPress has one already in `$wp_query->current_post`.

```
<?php while (have_posts()): the_post() ?>
    <?php if ($wp_query->current_post % 2 == 0): ?>
        even
    <?php else: ?>
        odd
    <?php endif ?>
<?php endwhile ?>
```

If you use a custom `WP_Query` instance as iEmanuele suggested then it will be `$query->current_post` instead.

Answer (score 4):

[Please don't use query_posts();](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts), use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class or [`get_posts();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) instead.

To target odd/even posts in your loop:

```
//I will use WP_Query class instance
$args( 'post_type' => 'recipe', 'posts_per_page' => 5 );

//Set up a counter
$counter = 0;

//Preparing the Loop
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

//In while loop counter increments by one $counter++
if( $query->have_posts() ) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); $counter++;

    //We are in loop so we can check if counter is odd or even
    if( $counter % 2 == 0 ) : //It's even

        the_title(); //Echo the title of post
        the_content(); //Echo the content of the post

    else: //It's odd

        if( has_post_thumbnail() ) : //If the post has the post thumbnail, show it
            the_post_thumbnail();
        endif;

    endif;

endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); endif;
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can have a new variable to count the number of posts, then increase it inside the *while loop* and then check if it is odd or even. Here's a sample code from [Blaskan theme](http://wordpress.org/themes/blaskan)'s loop.php file that displays an author's archives...

```
<?php // Start the loop ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php if ( ( is_archive() || is_author() ) && ( !is_category() && !is_tag() ) ) : // Archives ?>
    <li>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'blaskan' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
      <time datetime="<?php the_date('c'); ?>"><?php print get_the_date(); ?></time>
    </li>
<?php else: // Else ?>
```

Modified code that displays the date of publishing, only on even numbered posts in an author's archives...

```
<?php $posts_count = 1; // Start the loop ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php ++$posts_count; ?>

<?php if ( ( is_archive() || is_author() ) && ( !is_category() && !is_tag() ) ) : // Archives ?>
    <li>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'blaskan' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
      <?php if($posts_count % 2): ?> <time datetime="<?php the_date('c'); ?>"><?php print get_the_date(); ?></time> <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
<?php else: // Else ?>
```